# Подбор случайной пары игроков для мультиплеера (backend)

Tags: node.js, unity3d, socket.io

Данные передаются с мобильного телефона на сервер где они записываются в различные объекты-контейнеры в формате:

```
Global_Europe[data.accountId] = {
    player_region: data.player_region,
    id: socket.id,
    x: data.x,
    y: data.y,
    z: data.z
  };
```

Задача распределить этих игроков в комнаты по два и принимать эти данные уже не на мобилке, а на билде webgl. Пытался реализовать через socket io rooms, но socket.id мобильного устройства и webgl будут разными. Прошу помочь